# What is the elevation unit of the Natural Earth's Shaded Relief raster?

Tags: raster, elevation, natural-earth, shaded-relief

I need to use this raster data to extract elevation for points and polygons, but I am really confused about the unit of the pixel values

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-shaded-relief/

The pixel values are between 49 and 252, and oceans have higher pixel values than some land areas. How should I interpret the pixel values and convert them to meters?

Comment: Shaded relief does not present heights/depths but shadows. Image is light where the sun hits the hill best. You need digital elevation model, not shaded relief.

Comment: @user30184 If you can expand that with a bit more info you should add as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get heights or depths from a shaded relief raster. The purpose of shaded relief is described in [this tutorial](http://www.pcigeomatics.com/pdf/Creating_CSR-v10-v2.pdf):

> Shaded relief models indicate terrain displacements using a shadow
>   effect from evaluating the aspect  and slope relative to the sun's
>   azimuth angle and altitude  achieved with varying grey scale tones
>   resulting  in the darkening of one side of terrain features, such as
>   hills and ridges (the darker the shading, the  steeper the slope).

The tutorial is worth reading. There is also a dedicated web site about shaded relief http://www.shadedrelief.com/.

For getting the real elevation values you need a digital elevation model (DEM).